# Docker daemon throwing error while starting in Linux RHEL

Tags: linux, docker, containers, rhel

I am trying to start my dockerd daemon by this command - dockerd &
Then i start getting the error as below -

ERRO[0036] libcontainerd: failed to receive event from containerd: rpc error: code = 12 desc = unknown service types.API

This keeps rolling again and again and i am unable to start any container after that. If i close the session and open a new session, i could see docker ps is accessible. But i am unable to start any container. While starting the container I am getting error -

docker run hello-world

docker: Error response from daemon: unknown service types.API. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

Please let me know if any logs are needed.

Comment: depending on your version of RHEL, you might be [SOL](https://success.docker.com/Policies/Compatibility_Matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you start the docker daemon using `dockerd &` and not `systemctl start docker.service`?  This is probably the cause of your problem.

In order to start the daemon at boot, you need to run `systemctl enable docker.service`.  See [Getting Started with Containers](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html-single/getting_started_with_containers/).

Note that the kernel for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 only supports a limited subset of the functionality needed for container support, and I don't think anyone tests either the daemon or container images on that operating system version.

Comment: Thanks Florian. I have now started with systemctl command on the RHEL box.